# NativeScript App Data Binding Crash

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have an NativeScript App that crashes every time I try to bind an ObservableArray to my ListView.

When I comment out line 9 of my standings.js file, the login function runs, and the standings load function runs, but when I uncomment that line the whole app crashes, and the login function doesn't even run.

Here is standings.js:

```
var dialogsModule = require("ui/dialogs");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var StandingsListViewModel = require("../../shared/view-models/standings-list-view-model");
var page;

var standingsList = new StandingsListViewModel([]);
var pageData = new Observable({
    standingsList: standingsList
});

exports.loaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;

    standingsList.load();
};
```

standings.xml:

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
<GridLayout rows="auto, *" columns="2*, *">
    <Label id="header" text="Standings" colSpan="2" horizontalAlignment="center"/>

    <ListView items="{{ standingsList }}" id="standingsList" row="1" colSpan="2">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ place }}" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"/>
            <Label text="{{ username }}" col="2" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"/>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
```

And standings-list-view-model.js:

```
var config = require("../../shared/config");
var fetchModule = require("fetch");
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

function StandingsListViewModel(items) {
var viewModel = new ObservableArray(items);

viewModel.load = function() {
    console.log("hit");
    var url = config.apiURI + "getStandings.cfm?weekid=397";
    return fetch(url)
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(function(data) {
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data._bodyInit);
        var users = parsedData.users;
        users.forEach(function(standing) {
            viewModel.push({
                place: standing.place,
                username: standing.username
            });
        });
        console.log(viewModel._array[0].username);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    });
};

return viewModel;

}

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

module.exports = StandingsListViewModel;
```

Any help or ideas about how to debug better would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here `var standingsList = new StandingsListViewModel([]);`. Using a `new` will create an object of a variable type. But here you defined `StandingListViewModel()` as a function, not a class that maybe the `standingList` is not returned as you expect. Replace that line by:

```
var standingsList = StandingsListViewModel([]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting the same error. Do you know where I can look into these data structures in more detail? I'm sure the solution is in there somewhere.